# Change behavior of "use-input" in vue.js

Tags: typescript, vue.js, quasar-framework

I'm using vue.js with typescript to have an input field, in which the user can either select items from a drop-down menu or actually type in some custom input. There are different use cases: either custom input is allowed or only input from the drop-down menu (which is hardcoded).

I found out, that I can use "use-input" to be able to activate or deactivate user input from the keyboard. Unfortunately by now, I can only control this behavior by either having "use-input" inside the `<q-select></q-select>` or remove it completely. Instead I would like to be able to control the input behavior by some flag, e.g. `use-input="False"`. This I tried and got the error message:

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "useInput". Expected Boolean, got String with value "False".
```

Now I assume, that the property "useInput" can actually take a boolean, but somehow I didn't find the right syntax to actually make it working. 
Also, I didn't find any documentation about `useInput`, so maybe somebody here has already worked with it?

here is a small snipped of the code, hope this is enough to see the problem:

```
<template>
  <q-item
    class="item"
  >
    <div
      class="item-content column"
      style="width: 100%;"
      @click.passive="click"
    >
      <q-select
        use-input="False"
        @input="inputChanged"
      >
  </q-select>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
:use-input="false"
```

When adding : before your attribute in the template, vue knows that you are inputting javascript. This means that you can add a boolean, method, object, array etc. and if you want to add a string, you can wrap it in '' like this:

```
:some-attribute="'some string'"
```

Also remember, true and false are not capitalized.

Finally, you can also add template literals, which allows you to mix strings with javascript like this:

```
:some-attribute="`My name is ${myName}`"
```

You can read about that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), it's super useful.

Comment: thanks a lot Thomas Bay for the quick help! Somehow the ":" slipped my attention, when looking at other vue js code...